# How to interpret the prediction in this plot of classification tree?

Tags: r, machine-learning, decision-tree, h2o

[image]I have followed this tutorial and was able to reproduce the results. However, the last graph confuses me. I understand most of the time it's probability, but why are there **negative** numbers? Since the response is Survived, how to interpret the numbers in the predictions? How to convert those numbers to Yes and No?

https://www.h2o.ai/blog/finally-you-can-plot-h2o-decision-trees-in-r/

**EIDT 11/19/2019:** by the way, I did find a similar post on Cross Validated. The answer was not certain since it ended with a question mark.
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/374569/may-somebody-help-with-interpretation-of-trees-from-h2o-gbm-see-as-photo-attach

I filtered the data using the logic in the tree and looked at the unique prediction of the subset. I was able to find the threshold for 'yes' and 'no' predictions. I also changed the original code (starting line 34) so that the leaf shows the ultimate result of the numbers. However, this is just a way to hack the plot. If someone can tell me how the numbers are derived, that would be great.

```
    if(class(left_node)[[1]] == 'H2OLeafNode')
      leftLabel = ifelse(left_node@prediction >= threshold, 'Yes', 'No')
  else
    leftLabel = left_node@split_feature

  if(class(right_node)[[1]] == 'H2OLeafNode')
    rightLabel = ifelse(right_node@prediction >= threshold, 'Yes', 'No')
  else
    rightLabel = right_node@split_feature
```

Comment: The simple method would say "yes" if above 0.5, "no" otherwise. The better way would be to do some reading about how to pick an *operating point* on a ROC curve or precision-recall curve. In either case, this is a statistical modeling question, not a programming question, so it would be a better fit at stats.stackexchange (though I'd encourage you to do some background reading about operating points before asking there).

Comment: @Gregor thanks! What confused me was the negative numbers in the plot.

Comment: The values seem roughly centred around 0.0, so I'm guessing -1 and +1 are being used as the two factor levels, and 0.0 is supposed to mean if you reach that leaf then that person has a 50-50 chance of survival?  (What I'm not sure of, and the reason I'm not posting an answer, is if this -1 to +1 behaviour is coming from H2O, R, or the data.tree library.)

Comment: BTW, I think this question is good and belongs here. If you post it at stats.stackechange it will most likely get closed as "specific to a library or language, nothing to do with stats, try posting it on StackOverflow" ;-)

Comment: Thanks @DarrenCook! The prediction (I believe) comes from the utility function `addChildren()`. When I do `titanicH2oTree@root_node@left_child@left_child@left_child@left_child@prediction`, the number lines up the leave in the plot. Does that mean anything?

Answer (score 1):

Since the picture is a GBM plot, it’s not as straightforward as you might like, since the inference calculation does some math on the value extracted from the leaf of the tree.

The actual code is here:

https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-genmodel/src/main/java/hex/genmodel/algos/gbm/GbmMojoModel.java

Look at the score0 function.

My advice would be to build a 1-tree DRF instead, and then write a short java program and try to single-step it in a java debugger.

The java snippet to start from is how to compile and run a MOJO in this document:

http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-genmodel/javadoc/index.html

If you do this, you will be able to step through the exact steps that produce the answer (for GBM as well if you prefer), and nothing will be unknown at that point.

Comment: From the first link, I guess the values are logit since the distribution is Bernoulli, so I try to recover the logit using `1 / (1 + exp(-f))`. The values look right but when I try to match them with the values from h2o.predict(), I discovered that I could not reproduce any of them...

Comment: I filtered the data using the tree logic and see what's the unique prediction of that subset. I was able to get some simple threshold such as if the prediction is bigger than -0.002 then yes.